# delete all tables with the same prefix in database

Tags: database

I did the installation of a theme in Magento through the quick start of the theme, however, duplicate tables were created in the db.
So the tables have no prefix and prefix with their duplication.

The question is, how do I delete all tables with the prefix?

the prefix is​​: #_

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589278/sql-deleting-tables-with-prefix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MageWH send the solve question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589278/sql-deleting-tables-with-prefix

For someone with the same question, here is the script:

```
SELECT CONCAT( 'DROP TABLE ', GROUP_CONCAT(table_name) , ';' ) 
    AS statement FROM information_schema.tables 
    WHERE table_schema = 'database_name' AND table_name LIKE 'myprefix_%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a program of your choice, I prefer Sequel pro and mark the tables and delete them. Check "Force delete", so they are gone after this.

Comment: Yes, but I want some script to do this, there are a lot of tables

Comment: No there are only around 300 and you can just mark them all, because they are all together?

Comment: they are all together, prefix, non-prefix, and other prefix.

Comment: I don't understand. At least phpmyadmin and sequelPro order the tables by name, you can even write a query which gives you all the table names with the prefix, then take this list and run it through a PHP script which generates all the DROP TABLE statements. this is a lot faster than this discussion here. Maybe I don't understand the problem.

Comment: hey, @MageWH solved my question. My database created 3 types of the same tables, and I dont know why.